# Ошибка: Индекс за пределами диапазона

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и почему выдает данную ошибку?

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            human[human.Count - 1].SetHobby(hobb.Text);
            hobbView2.Items.Add(hobb.Text);
            hobb.Clear();
        }
```

```
       private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            teacher[teacher.Count - 1].SetSalary(Convert.ToDouble(salar.Text));
            MessageBox.Show("Salary Add: "+salar.Text);
            salar.Clear();
        }
```

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            student[student.Count - 1].SetCard(SubST.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text));
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { SubST.Text, textBox11.Text });
            listView1.Items.Add(item1);
            SubST.Clear();
            textBox11.Clear();          
        }
```

```
        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chief[chief.Count - 1].SetDay(textBox15.Text,textBox16.Text,textBox17.Text);
            textBox17.Clear();
            textBox15.Clear();
            textBox16.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: `human[human.Count - 1]` по какому индексу вы будете обращаться в подобном коде, если коллекция будет пустая?

Answer (score 1):

```
chief[chief.Count - 1]
```

При пустом списке (`chief.Count` равном нулю) обращение идет к элементу с индексом `-1`.